# Cannot implement abstract method with a subclass of an abstract argument

Tags: java, interface

Say I'm making a class that implements an interface, and have code like this:

```
public void setGoalLocation(Location loc)
{
    goal = loc;
}
```

The code doesn't compile, because it demands that I implement a "setGoalLocation(Ilocation loc)" method, where "Ilocation" is an interface and "Location" is an actual concrete class that implements it.

This means that I have to do something like this:

```
public void setGoalLocation(ILocation loc)
{
    goal = (Location)loc;
}
```

That just seems really awkward. And funnily enough, Java doesn't seem to care about other methods returning Location instead of the interface ILocation. This works:

```
public Location getStartLocation()
{
    return start;
}
```

...even though the "required" method would be a "public **ILocation** getStartLocation". Can anyone explain why this is, and any help for making the code less awkward? I'd like to be able to use a Location as a parameter, not an ILocation.

Comment: Please share complete class and interface definitions.

Comment: This is correct behavior. If some code is communicating with your class only through the interface then the code doesn't know that your class only accept a `Location` value. It expects that your class allows any `ILocation` value.

Comment: Regarding the return value: Code which communicates with your class  through the interface expects any `ILocation` return value. Since `Location` matches this criteria using it as a more specific return type is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the interface requires a method that accepts *anything* as an argument that is a subtype of `ILocation`, not just an object of the specific type `Location`. If you had another concrete type `Position` that was a subtype of `ILocation`, then implementing the interface would require you to accept a `Position` object as well as a `Location` object.

Note that in your work-around using a cast, you'd get a `ClassCastException` at run time if you happened to pass a `Position` instead of a `Location` object.

As a design issue, to get around this you could define your interface as a generic:

```
interface <T extends ILocation> TheInterface {
    void setGoalLocation(T loc);
}
```

Then your concrete class can bound the generic parameter:

```
public class MyClass implements TheInterface<Location> {
    public void setGoalLocation(Location loc) {
        . . .
    }
}
```

As to return types, that works because any `Location` object is an `ILocation`, so when you return a `Location` you are returning an `ILocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports covariant return types where the return type of a method in a subclass (or interface implementation) can return a subclass (or implementation) of the declared type. So in general, the following is allowed

```
public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public class C {
    A getSomething();
}

public class D extends C {
    B getSomething();
}
```

If the interface has a method that takes an interface type, you cannot override it with a different signature.

```
public interface I {
    void setSomething(ISomething somethingInterface);
}
```

You cannot do

```
public class Something implements ISomething {}

public class MyI implements I {
    void setSomething(Something somethingInterface);
}
```